# displaying string containing \t character in text object

Tags: string, matlab, textbox

In a text object, I would like to display a string assembled using sprintf() from many parts with different lengths. I want to separate the parts with Tabs. First, I create the string and it contains the Tab characters correctly. When I set the 'String' property of the text object to the string, get() gives back the correct string, but on the screen I see the string with Tabs skipped. I put below a simple script demonstrating the problem:

```
fh=figure;
axis off;
th=text(.5,.5,'trash');
s=sprintf('%s\t%s\t%i','trash','pp',7)
set(th,'String',s);
get(th,'String')
delete(fh);
```

I don't want to separate the parts of the string with spaces, as the substrings might have different lengths.

Any help is appreciated!

Laszlo

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: tabs are not a save way to achieve what you seem to want. but with `printf` you could use "%20s", to if you are sure that your string is never longer then 20 characters. see the `printf` documentation for further details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include that I work in Matlab R2013a...